# Make function return boolean and implement AI in tic/tac/toe game

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics, tic-tac-toe

I have made a tic/tac/toe game but I want to create a computer player that controls "O" while the user controls "X".

For the `clicked` function in my code, I am trying to return a boolean but I am not sure if I am doing it right. The function returns `True` if the user's click operations were successful. If the user clicks on a position that is already outside of the board area, the move is invalid and the function should then return `False`.  My code:

```
import turtle
import time
import random 

pieces = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]
turn = "X"
def drawgame(brd):
    # draw board
    turtle.setup(600, 600)
    turtle.bgcolor("silver")
    turtle.color("white")
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.width(10)
    turtle.up()

    # Horizontal bars
    turtle.goto(-300, 100)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(600)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(-300, -100)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(600)
    turtle.up()

    # Vertical bars
    turtle.goto(-100, 300)
    turtle.setheading(-90)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(600)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(100, 300)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(600)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.color("blue")
    x, y = -300, 300
    for pos in pieces:
        if pos == "X":
            # Draw X
            turtle.up()
            turtle.goto(x + 20, y - 20)
            turtle.setheading(-45)
            turtle.down()
            turtle.forward(226)
            turtle.up()
            turtle.goto(x + 180, y - 20)
            turtle.setheading(-135)
            turtle.down()
            turtle.forward(226)
            turtle.up()

        elif pos == "O":
            #Draw O
            turtle.up()
            turtle.goto(x + 100, y - 180)
            turtle.setheading(0)
            turtle.down()
            turtle.circle(80)
            turtle.up()
        x += 200
        if x > 100:
            x = -300
            y -= 200


def clicked(board, x, y):
    #sig: list(str), int, int -> NoneType
    global turn, pieces
    turtle.onscreenclick(None)  # disabling handler when inside handler
    column = (x + 300) // 200
    row = (y - 300) // -200
    square = int(row * 3 + column)
    print("User clicked ", x, ",", y, " at square ", square)

    if pieces[square] == "_":
        pieces[square] = turn
        if turn == "X":
            turn = "O"
        else:
            turn = "X"
        drawgame(pieces)
    else:
        print("That square is already taken")
    turtle.onscreenclick(clicked)

def computer_AI(board):
    #sig: list(str) -> NoneType

def gameover(board):
    #sig: list(str) -> bool
    #checks gameover on board if there is a three in a row pattern or not

def handler(x, y):
    #sig: int, int -> NoneType
    if clicked(the_board, x, y):
        drawgame(the_board)
        if not gameover(pieces):
            computer_AI(pieces)
            drawgame(pieces)
            gameover(pieces)


def main():
    #Runs the game 
    turtle.tracer(0,0)
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.onscreenclick(handler)
    drawgame(pieces)
    turtle.mainloop()

main()
```

I am trying to achieve this output: [image]

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For my `clicked` function in my code, I am trying to return a bool but I
>   am not sure if I am doing it right.

The `clicked()` function is an event hander, it doesn't return *anything* to *anyone*.  We have to design based on that.  I've reworked your code below, combining the `hander()` and `clicked()` functions, such that it now "plays".  That is, the user goes first, and is "X", and then the computer responds as player "O":

```
import turtle
import random

board = ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]

def drawgame(board):
    # draw board
    turtle.setup(600, 600)
    turtle.bgcolor("silver")
    turtle.color("white")
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.speed('fastest')
    turtle.width(10)
    turtle.up()

    # Horizontal bars
    turtle.goto(-300, 100)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(600)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(-300, -100)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(600)
    turtle.up()

    # Vertical bars
    turtle.setheading(-90)
    turtle.goto(-100, 300)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(600)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(100, 300)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(600)
    turtle.up()

    turtle.color("blue")
    x, y = -300, 300

    for pos in board:
        if pos == "X":
            # Draw X
            turtle.up()
            turtle.goto(x + 20, y - 20)
            turtle.setheading(-45)
            turtle.down()
            turtle.forward(226)
            turtle.up()
            turtle.goto(x + 180, y - 20)
            turtle.setheading(-135)
            turtle.down()
            turtle.forward(226)
            turtle.up()
        elif pos == "O":
            # Draw O
            turtle.up()
            turtle.goto(x + 100, y - 180)
            turtle.setheading(0)
            turtle.down()
            turtle.circle(80)
            turtle.up()

        x += 200
        if x > 100:
            x = -300
            y -= 200

def handler(x, y):
    # sig: list(str), int, int -> NoneType

    turtle.onscreenclick(None)  # disabling handler when inside handler

    column = (x + 300) // 200
    row = (y - 300) // -200
    square = int(row * 3 + column)

    if board[square] == "_":
        board[square] = "X"
        drawgame(board)
        if not gameover(board):
            computer_AI(board)
            drawgame(board)

            if not gameover(board):
                turtle.onscreenclick(handler)  # allow player to take a turn
    else:
        print("That square is already taken!")
        turtle.onscreenclick(handler)  # allow player to retake turn

def computer_AI(board): # sig: list(str) -> NoneType

    """ stupid robot player, just picks randomly from what's available """

    available = [index for index, character in enumerate(board) if character == "_"]

    if available:
        index = random.choice(available)
        board[index] = "O"

def gameover(board):
    # sig: list(str) -> bool
    # checks game over on board if there is a three in a row pattern or not

    pass  # to be implemented!

    return False

def main():
    # Runs the game
    turtle.hideturtle()
    turtle.onscreenclick(handler)
    drawgame(board)
    turtle.mainloop()

main()
```

To do: the logic to determine if the game is over, and who won, still doesn't exist, so you need to write that.  Currently it just returns `False` to indicate the game isn't over.  The `computer_AI()` code has no smarts at all, it simply notes all the open squares and picks one at random.  You need to improve on this.

Comment: I finally did it! But now i have this horrible error

Comment: I put it in a new question